# -bash : apt-get install command not found в программе Putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, telegram-bot, putty

Я написал Телеграм бота на Питоне. Купил VDS сервер. Залил все файлы на сервер через *Filezilla*. Вроде все успешно закинулось. Теперь мне нужно запустить бота на сервере. Сперва собирался установить библиотеки. Для этого использовал программу *Putty*. Написал:

```
apt-get install python3
```

На что получил ошибку:

```
-bash :apt-get install command not found
```

Предполагаю, что **apt-get** не установлен. Но понятия не имею, как его установить на Putty.

Также хочу узнать, какие лучше способы по запуску Телеграм бота на сервере, `screen` или `systemd`?

Comment: У вас точно Ubuntu?

Comment: windows котором установлен putty. ОС на сервере Ubuntu

Comment: Это понятно, а на сервере что?

Comment: centos-6-x86_64-minimal

Comment: попробуйте /usr/local/sbin/apt-get может path слетел в профиле

Comment: no such file or directory

Comment: В последних версиях Ubuntu *upt-get* заменили на *apt*. Попробуйте просто *apt install*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так поэтому и нет `apt-get`, что это не Ubuntu. В CentOS пакетный менеджер `yum`. Для установке Python 3 делайте так:

1. `sudo yum -y update` – обновить пакетный менеджер.
2. `sudo yum -y install yum-utils` – установить доп. утилиты.
3. `sudo yum -y groupinstall development` – установить утилиты для разработчиков.
4. `sudo yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm` – установить Inline with Upstream Stable (IUS).
5. `sudo yum -y install python36u` – установить наконец Питон 3.6.

Проверяем правильность установки:

```
python3.6 -V
```

Должно вывести версию:

```
Python 3.6.1
```

Вероятно, Вам также понадобится PIP:

```
sudo yum -y install python36u-pip
```

После этого можно будет устанавливать модули Питона:

```
sudo pip3.6 install package_name
```

Вероятно также Вам понадобятся дополнительные утилиты для разработки на Питоне (некий переходник для IUS):

```
sudo yum -y install python36u-devel
```

Если что, [вот источник инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7).

Comment: Благодарю, помогло! Так же хотел бы у вас поинтересоваться каким мне способом запустить бота на сервере? Screen или Systemd? И есть ли к ним инструкций?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал выбирать между SystemD и SupervisorD. В начале можно попробовать использовать только `nohup`, если эта команда есть в CentOS.  И конечно, по всем этим вещам очень много и документации, и форумов, и статей; но большинство материалов на английском, надеюсь, это не проблема.

Comment: Хорошо буду разбираться. Еще раз спасибо за совет, он мне пригодится. Рад вашей помощи

Comment: @AivanF., *nohup* есть везде.